# matrix and eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

for n by n matrix A, all of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are bigger than or equal to 0.

Also, the norm of $F_A : X \rightarrow AX : R^n \rightarrow R^n$ is equal to the squre root of the max value of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$

Can you give me a hint? plz.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For all vectors $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$
x^TA^TAx=(Ax)^T(Ax)=\Vert Ax\Vert^2.
$$

Comment: Thx. can you give me a hint of the second one, too?

Comment: I think I already did :-)

Comment: IOW, read it left-to-right and right-to-left

Comment: can you be more specific? I don't know how to solve second one

Comment: Do you know the definition of the norm of a linear mapping?